# how to add dynamically created object into a Container

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I am trying to create ListModels dynamically, and insert these ListModels into a Container.

I get a variable number of ListModels, each with variable content, from a backend system.  Based on the user's interaction with the GUI, one of those ListModels needs to be loaded into a known ListView.  The client wants to avoid Qt/C++, so I am looking to solve this via QML.

How do I get a dynamically created object (in my case, a ListModel) into a Container?  This code does not work:

```
  property string strID;
  property string strName;

  Container {
    id: functionListContainer;
  }

  // create ListModel
  var newObject = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQml.Models 2.14; ListModel { }", mainWindow);
  ...
  // dynamically append elements into the ListModel
  newObject.append({ deviceID: strID, deviceName: strName })
  ...
  // add ListModel to Container
  functionListContainer.addItem(newObject);
```

`createQmlObject` and `append` seem to work as intended. I get this error when running `addItem` code above:

> "Could not convert argument 0 at"
>   ...
>   "Passing incompatible arguments to C++ functions from JavaScript is dangerous and deprecated."
>   "This will throw a JavaScript TypeError in future releases of Qt!"

Any idea regarding how to get this to work?  I know that addItem is expecting an Item, not an Object, but I do not know how to get this to work.  I have tried replacing `var` with `property Item newItem` and `property QtObject newObject` [combined with  `addItem(newObject.item)`], and all give (seemingly identical) errors.  Is it a simple issue of casting the object into an Item?  If so, what is the syntax that needs to be used?

Lastly, assuming I do have a Container with *N* ListModels, is it possible to refer to the container directly in the ListView? i.e.:

```
  property int idx;

  Container {
    id: functionListContainer;
  }

  // add ListModels to container...

 // use ListModel inside container
 ListView {
   ...
   model: functionListContainer.itemAt(idx);
   ...
 }
```

I know that ListView is expecting a ListModel or something equivalent.  But I am not sure how to connect the ListView with a Container containing ListModels, or if it is even possible.

If I were to summarize my problem, I am trying to have a ListView display different ListModels based on context, and I am trying to do this within a pure-QML framework as much as possible.  Both of my questions above related to this.  It would be helpful even only to clarify that this is not an option and that it is necessary to use another method like clearing and populating the ListModel (suggestions welcome).

Comment: If you already get the models from C++, why not take an extra step and provide them as QAbstractItemModel? Seems that would greatly improve the code structure, making it possible to reference them by index and assigning them to `ListView`. If you don't want to do that, you can add a property to `functionListContainer` (javascript array) and append them to that

Comment: Hi Amfasis. Thanks for the suggestion. Sounds like QAbstractItemModel would be a good fit. However, we are trying to avoid C++ as much as possible due to specific customer-driven maintenance concerns, so that won't be an option. I just updated my question based upon your inputs.  A JavaScript Array is my 2nd option, and I know it will work. I would like to know if there was a way to get this to work with containers and if the only reason I am not able to get it to work is due to my lack of my knowledge regarding QML syntax. There is so much that isn't explicitly documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add a `QObject` (since `ListModel` is inherited from `QAbstractListModel`, which is in turn inherited from `QObject`) as a visual item using the `addItem` function. However, in QML a `QObject` (or `QtObject`) is regarded as an "storage element".

What you want to do it add the `contentData` of the `Container`:

```
Container {
    id: functionListContainer
}

      // create ListModel
      var newObject = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQml.Models 2.14; ListModel { }", mainWindow);
      ...
      // dynamically append elements into the ListModel
      newObject.append({ deviceID: strID, deviceName: strName })
      ...
      // add ListModel to Container
      functionListContainer.contentData.push(newObject)
```

The `contentData` property is the place where all children reside in the `Container`; `QObject` *and* `QQuickItem` (note that `QQuickItem` is inherited from `QObject`).

---

About referencing the lists, this also becomes easy when using the `contentData` property:

```
    // create ListModel
    var newObject = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQml.Models 2.14; ListModel { objectName: \"the_list\" }", mainWindow);

    ...
    // add ListModel to Container
    functionListContainer.contentData.push(newObject)

    console.log(functionListContainer.contentData[0])
```

will yield:

```
qml: QQmlListModel(0x55bcb7119720, "the_list")
```

---

Note that this is almost the same as using a Javascript array, the documentation of QQmlListProperty (which is what `contentData` is) states it is transparent.

Comment: Thank you! I hoped there was syntax that allowed it. I had read about the contentData (and contentModel), but did not know what syntax to use.  This worked beautifully!